# BigQuery returned Premature EOF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, domo

I have a table in bigquery with around 32 million rows and 85 columns with size of 22 GB. (It is a physical table not a view or temporary table) I am using this table as a datasource in Domo. This is the domo connector I am using: https://www.domo.com/appstore/connector/google-bigquery-service-connector/overview .

I am getting the "Domo is ready, but BigQuery returned Premature EOF. Please try again later." error in Domo, there are no further details availbale from Domo on this error. As per suggestion from Domo support I have tried using "allow large results" option too, still it has the same error.  When I run a query in Bigquery editor on the same dataset is works fine and complete execution in 17sec.

Are there other options I should try?

I don't think volume of data is a issue because yesterday I got the same error on another dataset in domo that connects to table in bigquery that has only 0.7 million row.

Are there any bigquery limits that are causing this error?